# JOIN table, receiving NULL answers

Tags: mysql, join

I have a problem on a script I'm writing and I don't know where I'm wrong.
I have multiple tables that are being filled from some txt files.
Afterwards I ALTER a table adding a column that must be filled from the result of a JOIN with two other tables. 
More specific in my current db I'm trying to insert in table 2 the id of the doctors that are currently in table 1 and 2. One table contains the id and name, and the 2nd the name.

Running this script:

```
insert into Intermediara.id_provizoriumed
select  Medici.id_medic is not null
FROM Medici
LEFT Join Intermediara
ON Medici.Nume  COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci =Intermediara.NumeMedic;
```

or

```
Insert into Intermediara(id_provizoriumed)  
Select DISTINCT Pacienti.Id_pacient 
FROM Pacienti
left JOIN Intermediara
ON Pacienti.NumePacient  COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci = Intermediara.NumePacient;
```

will result me in NULL answers;
Any ideas, please? :<

*More info on the project intself:

I'm using a procedure to create the tables:

```
 delimiter $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE init() 
 begin

 CREATE TABLE Medici (
 Nume VARCHAR(50),
 Prenume VARCHAR(225),
 Statut ENUM ('primar', 'specialist'),
 Specialitate VARCHAR(20),
 UNIQUE (Nume, Prenume)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci;

 ALTER TABLE Medici ADD COLUMN Id_medic int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;


 ALTER TABLE Medici ADD COLUMN Tip ENUM ('primar', 'specialist') AFTER Prenume;
 ALTER TABLE Medici DROP COLUMN Statut;

 DESCRIBE Medici;


 CREATE TABLE Pacienti (
 Id_pacient int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 NumePacient VARCHAR(50),
 PrenumePacient VARCHAR(100),
 UNIQUE (NumePacient, PrenumePacient))DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci;

 DESCRIBE Pacienti;

 CREATE TABLE Cabinete (
 Id_cabinet int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Denumire VARCHAR(50),
 UNIQUE (Denumire));

 DESCRIBE Cabinete;

 CREATE TABLE Vizite (
 IntervalData DATETIME,
 id_m int,
 id_p int,
 id_Cab int,
 FOREIGN KEY (id_m) REFERENCES Medici(Id_medic),
 FOREIGN KEY (id_p) REFERENCES Pacienti(Id_pacient),
 FOREIGN KEY (id_Cab) REFERENCES Cabinete(Id_cabinet)
 );

 DESCRIBE Vizite;

 CREATE TABLE Intermediara (
 DataVizita VARCHAR(50),
 OraIntrare TIME,
 NumePacient VARCHAR(50),
 PrenumePacient VARCHAR(50),
 NumeMedic VARCHAR(50),
 PrenumeMedic VARCHAR(50),
 Cabinet VARCHAR(50)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_romanian_ci;

 DESCRIBE Intermediara;
 end$$
 delimiter ;
```

Afterwards I'm loading the data in the tables Medici and Intermediara;
Then adding the info I need in:

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO Pacienti(NumePacient, PrenumePacient) SELECT NumePacient, PrenumePacient FROM Intermediara;
 INSERT IGNORE INTO Cabinete(Denumire) SELECT Cabinet FROM intermediara;
```

And then what I'm trying to do is to add in Intermediara after adding:

```
 ALTER TABLE Intermediara add column id_provizoriumed int collate utf8_romanian_ci;
 ALTER TABLE Intermediara add column id_provizoriupac int collate utf8_romanian_ci;
 ALTER TABLE Intermediara add column id_provizoriucab int collate utf8_romanian_ci;
```

to add the id from Medici (id_medic) in Intermediara by doing a JOIN having Medici.Nume and Intermediara.NumeMedic in the tables, the id must be distinct;

Comment: How about adding `WHERE Pacienti.Id_pacient IS NOT NULL` and `WHERE Cabinete.id_cabinet IS NOT NULL` respectively?

Comment: Won't let me since it will find it as an error in the code.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry done. I've updated the post.

Comment: Use just `JOIN` if you don't want NULL.

Comment: And more specific, how exactly should I write the code using just JOIN? You mean without DISTINCT or what exactly should be changed?

Comment: Tin simply means remove 'left' from your query

Comment: By simply using the JOIN command the workbench will run the code for the 10 mins until it gives me the error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query." because of the time it takes. The file I'm working with has more then 1kk lines which apparently takes allot to process. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some other suggestions?